# How can I access the data set before the most recently posted ones in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image: Firebase Database data structure]

Currently I have a code for firebase cloud functions that is able to read the latest data set coming in using the onWrite function. However, I wish to be able to read the data set directly before the latest data set (as shown in the picture where my latest would for EG be LHYfA9GkpwOMS0OysUd and the previous data set would be LHYF9jlBmlQL5qD19-D). Is there a way to do this with firebase cloud functions? The code below shows how I get the latest data and edit it! I want to use the latest data's etotal value to subtract that from the previous data's etotal value.

edit: my data values wont be replacing the previous set so I cannot use 'previous'

```
exports.editData = functions.database.ref('/AllData/immaphoton/A/{id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const afterData = change.after;
    if (afterData.exists()) {
        //console.log('hey');
        const data = afterData.val();
        // set of data to multiply by turns ratio
        var actualEIn = (data.ein)*200;
        var actualEOut = (data.eout)*200;
        var totalE = (actualEIn - actualEOut);
        var actualTotalPower = (data.tp)*200;
        var ISOts = (data.ts);
        // add timezone offset to milliseconds
        var localTS = moment(Date.parse(data.ts) + (8*1000*60*60)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        // need to change ts to suit each type of data
    }
    return admin.database().ref('/editedData/immaphoton/A').push({
        ein: actualEIn,
        eout: actualEOut,
        etotal: totalE,
        tp: actualTotalPower,
        timestamp: ISOts,
        localtime: localTS,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the key of the new child node, you can read the item before it by combining `orderByKey().limitToLast()`:

```
var key = context.params.id; // key of new/updated child
var ref = admin.database().ref('/editedData/immaphoton/A');
var query = ref.orderByKey().endAt(key).limitToLast(2);
query.once("child_added").then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

This code is not dependent on running in Cloud Functions, except for how it determines the value of `key`. If you can determine the key another way, this would run with any of the Firebase JavaScript SDKs.